# Removing an object with em->remove($user) removes all objects in table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a User entity that implements UserInterface to use with a RBAC system. I have not implemented the whole system yet. However, when I try to remove a user with the following code, the action removes all the users and other associated objects in other tables and then throws me an error. I am able to remove objects from other entities without issues.

User entity

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
 **
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="smallint")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * 
protected $id;

 **
 * @var string $username
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=20, unique=TRUE)
 * 
protected $username;

 **
 * @var string $password
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
 * 
protected $password;

 **
 * @var string $salt
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=255)
 * 
protected $salt;

 **
 * @var string $fullName
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="full_name", type="string", length=60, unique=TRUE)
 * 
protected $fullName;

 **
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_roles")
 * 
 * @var ArrayCollection $userRoles
 * 
protected $userRoles;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->userRoles = new ArrayCollection();
}
}
```

Delete action

```
public function deleteUserAction($id) {
$user = $em->getRepository('ACMECompanyBundle:User')->find($id);
$currentUser = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
if ($id == $currentUser->getId()) {
    return new Response("You cannot delete the current user");
}        
if (!$user) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('No user found for id '.$id);
}
try {
    $em->remove($user);
    $em->flush();
    $msg = "User deleted!";
    $code = "OK";
} catch (DBALException $e) {
    return new Response($e);
    $msg = "User cannot be deleted!";
    $code = "ERR";
}
$response = new Response(json_encode(array('code' => $code, 'msg' => $msg)));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
}
```

The error returned after all users are removed is

> InvalidArgumentException: You cannot refresh a user from the EntityUserProvider that does not contain an identifier. The user object has to be serialized with its own identifier mapped by Doctrine.

Answer (score 1):

You left out the definition for em in your action... define it with

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
```

and it should work. Unless you set it on the class itself, then you would need `$this->...`

Answer (score 0):

When doctrine removes the user, it also removes all rolles assigned to this user and all users assigned to these roles. So according your annotation schema this is the correct behavior because of cascade={"remove"} in $userRoles annotation and cascade={"remove"} in $users annotation in Role entity.

If you want to prevent cascade removing and want to keep cascade persistent remove "remove" argument from both user and role relations

Comment: Removed "remove" from both entities, updated schema and the issue persists. Created a new user and did not assign any role to it. Deleting this new user also removes all the existing roles and users. I can delete roles with no problem. Deleting a user empties the users table.

Comment: Did you override find method in the repository? If so check whether it returns one or more users. Also check post/preRemove events if you have some. Provide us more code with entire user entity class

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have my code on Gist [http://gist.github.com/3951463](http://gist.github.com/3951463) I do not have a UserRepository or any post or pre methods. I even tried with findOneBy(array('id'=>$id)).

Comment: Try to add 2 users with null parentId and remove one of them. If only one user is deleted replace "all" to "persist" in $children annotation or add $user->setParent(null) just after $parentUser->removeChildren($user);. If all users are removed then ill dig further.

Comment: It is still removing all users. Also, after I remove children from parent with `$parentUser->removeChildren($user)` and flush, the parent_id is not changing to 'null' and I can fetch the parent with `$user->getParent()`. Is this not supposed to work? should I just go with DBAL?

Comment: It works the right way. You unlink $user from $parentUser children container, but there is still link in $user to its parent, which you can remove by calling $user->setParent(null). Just before calling $em->remove($user); output sizeof($user->getChildren), is the result 0 or not?

Comment: setParent(null) does detach the child user and `sizeof($user->getParent())` is returning 0. But, deleting the child user after detaching is still removing all the user objects. :(